# Calling functions insight function / arguments

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments, concatenation

I am trying to write a function that takes functions as arguments (as many as it gets) and returns them. The function funcArg should return 'Called me'. I used Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); to create an array but I don't know how to call die functions in that array. Any ideas? Thanks!!

```
var caller = function() {
  return "Called ";
};
var adder = function() {
  return " me";
};
var funcArgs = function() {
  var myArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}
funcArgs(caller);
funcArgs(calleradder);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
var funcArgs = function() {
  var functions = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return functions.reduce(function(total, f) {
    return total + f();
  }, '');
};
```

The way this works if you start off with an array of functions. We then go through each function one at a time. We then call that function and append it to the result of the previous function. Breaking this down into simpler code would look like this:

```
var funcArgs = function() {
  var functions = [caller, adder];
  var result = '';
  result += functions[0](); // caller();
  result += functions[1](); // adder();
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This (last) solution however would only work if I knew how many arguments I will have..

Comment: @learningcoding it's not a solution, he's explaining how the first method works in more detail..

Comment: @learningcoding The last one isn't a solution. It's an explanation of what's going on when you call `funcArgs(caller, adder)`. When writing code like this, it's important to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of functions you can loop over them with `forEach`.

```
var caller = function() {
  return "Called "
}

var adder = function() {
  return " me"
}

var funcArgs = function() {
  var myArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  myArray.forEach(function (fn) {
    console.log(fn())
  })
}

funcArgs(caller, adder); // "Called me"
```

If you want to actually return the values, rather than just console.log them, you can use `reduce` to return the strings concatenated (or whatever else)

```
var funcArgs = function() {
  var myArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  return myArray.reduce(function (acc, fn) {
    return acc + fn()
  }, '')
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! Do you know how I would use here the concat method on the args?

Comment: What do you want to do with `concat`. What's the desired result?

Comment: "Called" and "me" which will be returned are suppose to be in one line like Called me opposed to being on separate lines

Comment: That's what my second function does.. the one using `reduce`. It's also what @Mike C's function does (they're the same function)

Comment: Yea I just double checked and it does. Thank you! Can you explain: In this case acc would be the first function, fn the second, why is that only the fn is called ( fn() ) but not the first one (acc) -Im sure it does, Im just trying to understand the code

Comment: Also the "" is the initial value, right? If I would remove that, I would get a weird output of 'function () {\n      return "Called";\n    } me' Could you please explain how the initial value avoids that? Thank you

Comment: Read the docs for reduce.. here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce